# How to properly execute this loop?

Tags: python

```
legalmoves = [
    "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4",
    "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8"
    "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"
    "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8"
    "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8"
    "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8"
    "g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8"
    "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8"
]
illegalmoves = ""
def play():

    Userpick = input("Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): ").lower()

    if Userpick in legalmoves:
        print("")
        print("The coordinates:", Userpick.upper(), ", is a legal move!")
    else:
        print("")
        print("The coordinates:", Userpick.upper(), ", is a illegal move!")
        print("")
play()





while True:
    print("")
    Userpick = input("Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): ").lower()
    if Userpick not in illegalmoves:
        print("")
        print("The coordinates:", Userpick.upper(), ", is a illegal move!")

    else:
        print("")
        print("The coordinates:", Userpick.upper(), ", is a legal move!")
```

I am trying to make this chessboard that whenever user inputs a letter and a number `ex:a1`, it will output as:`legal move`. if user inputs a number and a letter `ex:1a`, it will output as `illegal move`.

My issue is that whenever user inputs an illegal move (a number then a letter), it will prompt the user to enter a new move, when the user finally inputs the legal move such as `a1`, it will still output as an illegal move.

**Wrong output:**

```
Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): 6a

The coordinates: 6A , is a illegal move!

Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): a6

The coordinates: A6 , is a illegal move!

Please type a coordinate (EX:A2):
```

**Expected output:**

```
Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): 6a

The coordinates: 6A , is a illegal move!

Please type a coordinate (EX:A2): a6

The coordinates: A6 , is a legal move!

Please type a coordinate (EX:A2):
```

Comment: `Userpick not in illegalmoves` will always be true, because `illegalmoves` is empty.  You did it right in `pick()`, why aren't you using that function rather than rewriting it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the second and subsequent inputs become "illegal move!" is because the `illegalmoves` variable is empty.

```
if Userpick not in illegalmoves:
```

The following modifications would produce the expected results.

```
if Userpick not in legalmoves:
```